# Direct to particular view on click of user notifications

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have implemented push notifications in my project , on click of push notifications(in inactive , background and foreground mode) I am directing user to particular Viewcontroller  from appdelegate where there is the list of notifications, here is the code  it:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
 if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
                    print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
                }
   let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        let initialViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VANotificationTableViewController") as! VANotificationViewController

                        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
                        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                //showPushNotification(message: response.notification.request.content.body)

                completionHandler()
            }
```

Basically, I am making my notification view controller as my rootViewController
On click of back button from notification view controller it should show me Dashboard view controller , but the Dashboard view controller is coming without notification bar on top of it. 
Things that i have tried

- Self.dismiss
- Tried putting segue
- Setting dashboard controller as root view controller from back action on notification view controller

  Is there a way so I can navigate view to Notification ViewController from AppDelegate differently so the code works fine?

Answer (score 0):

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VANotificationTableViewController") as! VANotificationViewController
    let nav  = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: initialViewController)
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = nav
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    //showPushNotification(message: response.notification.request.content.body)
    completionHandler()}
```